# Ubuntu 16.04 desktop won't boot after clean install on Dell 5G 5090 - no bootable device found

Tags: 16.04, dell

I recently bought a Dell 5G 5090 desktop with NVidia RTX2060 GPU and Windows 10, to use in deep learning projects. I made a bootable USB per [Ubuntu's tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0) and installed 16.04.  After the install, boot fails with: **Critical Error Message - No bootable devices found.**

Question: How to properly install Ubuntu 16.04 on this computer?

Here's my info:

System info:
i7-9700K
SATA-0 2TB HDD
M.2 PCIe SSD-0 512 GB

Here are the steps I took for the installation:

```
F12 BIOS Setup:
Boot Sequence:
Windows Boot Manager unchecked, 
Boot List Option:
Legacy External Devices unchecked,
UEFI checked
Advanced Boot Options:
Enable Legacy Option ROM checked
(If I don't check this option, restarting the computer and after F12, the bootable USB does not show up)
Secure Boot\Secure Boot Enable:
Secure Boot Enable unchecked
Secure Boot Mode:
Deployed Mode unchecked,
Audit Mode checked
```

```
Restart computer, then press F12, the following is displayed:
Boot Mode is set to UEFI; Secure Boot: OFF; PTT is OFF;
Legacy External Device Boot:
USB Storage Device
Onboard NIC
UEFI Boot:
Windows Boot Manager
Other Options:
BIOS Setup, etc.
```

I select USB Storage Device.

There are several errors displayed but very quickly Ubuntu 16.04 Install (as superuser) pane pops up and I proceed to do a clean install, following the tutorial's recommended options.

During the 'Write the changes to disk?" The following partitions are formatted:
partition #1 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) as ext4
partition #5 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) as swap

At the end of the install, I'm prompted to restart. I remove the USB and click on the restart button on the Ubuntu pane.  The screen returns to where the errors were displayed and hangs. I press CTRL-ALT-DEL and the computer restarts with the error noted above.

I restart and uncheck the Enable Legacy Option ROM, but still get the same error: no bootable devices found.

Under Boot List Option: Add Boot Option:

I click on this and a warning window informs that File System Not Found!

Since I've wiped out the OS, I'm somewhat stuck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update 1:

Thank you for the very quick response - much appreciated.  The reason for 16.04 vs 18.04 is that I've set up all my deep learning/machine learning projects on another machine with 16.04 and a Python 3.6 env.  I want to maintain compatibility when transferring projects from one machine to another.

Since my initial post, I discovered a few things and got Ubuntu 16.04 LTS desktop successfully installed and running.

I realised that I had downloaded the 32-bit iso not the 64-bit for 16.04.  So I tried again to re-install Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit, but this time I unchecked Enable Legacy Option ROM in the BIOS setup.

I was able to get the proper boot window, allowing me to select ubuntu, and installation began.  Several notifications popped up, which I was not fast enough to capture with cell camera.  However, the installation progressed but abruptly failed at:

[Grub install failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBqma.jpg)

Update 2

I tried once more to re-install 16.04 64-bit iso.  The following things were noted:

[failed to detect board data for bus=pci](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyRS0.jpg)

[Continue in EUFI mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw4Y7.jpg)

At the installation type, I chose to erase disk rather erase Ubuntu 16.04 and reinstall:

[Erase disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/928CD.jpg)

Followed by installation type (let default):

[Partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whWeQ.jpg)

Installation took a lot longer than the first (32-bit), but eventually I was able to re-start.  I hope someone finds this helpful.

Update 3:

I checked whether Ubuntu loaded onto the SSD or not:

```
$ sudo lshw -short -C disk
H/W path        Device     Class          Description
=====================================================
/0/1/0.0.0      /dev/sda   disk           2TB ST2000DM008-2FR1
```

So it did not load onto my 500 GB SSD.  This is consistent with the error on the initial screen, indicating:

```
failed to fetch board data for bus=pci...
```

Question: How to get Ubuntu 16.04 to recognise the M.2 PCIe SSD-0 512 GB?

Comment: And it sounds like you booted installer in BIOS boot mode. You want to boot in UEFI mode, so install is UEFI to gpt partitioned drive. How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is how it installs. You may need to also turn on allow USB boot or similar USB setting in UEFI. https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln151664/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en General UEFI instructions:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI Have you updated UEFI and if SSD its firmware from Dell? UEFI/BIOS updates - Dell with (uefi >= 0.6.2 & dell >= 0.7.3) 
https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devicelist

Comment: @oldfred is there a way for Ubuntu 16.04 to recognise the M.2 PCIe SSD-0 512 GB?

Comment: Why install 16.04 to this new hardware? It doesn't support most of it. Try 18.04.

Comment: @Pilot6 thanks for the comment.  As mentioned in my updates, I have another machine running on a Python 3.6 env on Ubuntu 16.04 and would like to retain compatibility when transferring projects to the Dell 5G from the other Ubuntu machine.

Comment: @oldfred I think I found the answer I just pose: [https://www.dell.com/support/article/ca/en/cadhs1/sln299303/loading-ubuntu-on-systems-using-pcie-m2-drives?lang=en]

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 16.04 to recognise the M.2 PCIe SSD, change the SATA setting to AHCI on the BIOS Setup (F12 on my machine at boot-up) https://www.dell.com/support/article/ca/en/cabsdt1/sln299303/loading-ubuntu-on-systems-using-pcie-m2-drives?lang=en.  Once I did this, I was able to load Ubuntu 16.04 onto the SSD and reformat the HDD as a data-only drive.